# "NameError: name 'torch' is not defined" but torch is installed and imported

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I tried to install and import m3inference:

```
pip install m3inference
import m3inference
```

But I get the following error, how could I fix it?

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-50ee37ff85fa> in <module>
----> 1 import m3inference

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/m3inference/full_model.py in M3InferenceModel()
     10 
     11 class M3InferenceModel(nn.Module):
---> 12     def __init__(self, device='cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'):
     13         super(M3InferenceModel, self).__init__()
     14 

NameError: name 'torch' is not defined
```

I tried to install and import torch before doing the same with m3inference.

Comment: That file doesn't have an `import torch` line, and `torch` isn't imported in any of the modules it imports, either. It's a bug in the package, apparently.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? And what's your OS?

Comment: @joanis I tried with python 3.9.6, 3.8.8, and 3.7.6 and I got the same issue every time

Comment: It's odd that the code works at all, for the reason MattDMo says, but the author seems to have it working somewhere, so I don't quite get it. The package has a contact address listed at https://github.com/euagendas/m3inference you might have some luck contacting them?